# Set different number of markers in one align?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align, alignat

Is it possible to have a line have different number of markers as below? If we put '&&' after '**abcdefghij**', C,F,J would be all shifted right.

```
\begin{align}  
A & B && C \\  
D & E && F \\  
G & **abcdefghij** \\  
H & I && J \\  
\begin{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What's the point of having alignment point in an equation with a single line? There's nothing to align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't trying to achieve something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
A & B &\hspace{3em}& C \\
D & E && F \\
G & \mathrlap{abcdefghij}\\
H & I && J
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]